# Affine curve of an absolutely irreducible polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading the book "Field arithmetic" and found a theorem too had for me, corollary 5.4.2 (a). Namely,

Let $f\in\mathbb F_q[X,Y]$ be an absolutely irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. Denote the affine curve defined by the equation $f(X,Y)=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ by $\Gamma(\mathbb{F}_q)$, and let $d=\operatorname{deg}\Gamma$. The for each $m$ there exists $q_0$ such that $|\Gamma(\mathbb{F}_q)|\geq m$ for all $q\geq q_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. It is trivial as we have the inequality $|\Gamma(\mathbb{F}_q)|\geq q+1+(d-1)(d-2)\sqrt{q}-d$. Now $q+1$ grows faster than $(d-1)(d-2)\sqrt{q}-d$.